# How i can filter suggestion hint content in Visual Studio Code by moving arrow keys (Left and Right)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can cause suggestion manually, just putted cursor on some word and pressed "Ctrl+Space"

[Visual Studio Code Suggestion on existing word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj1ZA.png)

But if I use the left or right arrow keys, the suggestion-tooltip will hide. In many other IDE (eg QtCreator) - i can filtering suggestion content by moving arrows keys left and right on the word.

How to achieve similar behavior tips in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64641469/836330 This has been added to vscode v1.51.

Comment: looks like this is it