# how to keep shown the suggestions popup in vscode while moving the caret one character?

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to keep shown the suggestions popup in visual-studio-code while moving the caret one character in the same word, so I don't have to hit ctrl-space shortcut again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be possible with VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020):

> ### [Move cursor to select suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#move-cursor-to-select-suggestions)
>
> You can now move the cursor while suggestions are showing.
> For instance, you can trigger suggestions at the end of a word, move left to see more suggestions, and then use replace to overwrite the word.
>
> [image: Suggest Status Bar -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/images/1_51/suggest-left.gif]
>
> <sup>Theme: GitHub Light</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at this time. If you would to like to report a feature request, it's recommended to do it on their [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) I couldn't find any duplicates at this time; though it's hard to search for something like this because there are so many verbiage variants. They can better help you in that regard.

Alternatively, you can provide feedback inside the application itself using the 'Tweet Feedback' functionality.

Comment: Done : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102901